# Proftpd is missing mod_sql_passwd

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, proftpd

I did the setup for a `ProFTP` server on my Ubuntu workstation before-hand, but when replicating it on a Ubuntu server, `mod_sql_passwd` is simply missing.

When I enable the module, I get the following error:

> Fatal: LoadModule: error loading module 'mod_sql_passwd.c': Permission denied on line 51 of '/etc/proftpd/modules.conf'

`mod_sql_passwd` files (`.so` and `.c`) are simply missing, whereas on my workstation it was a simple matter of enabling the configuration.

The biggest difference with the server is that it's a release gap. I will be upgrading the server, which is at the latest `LTS` release, in case it's the reason why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does appear like there may be some differences in the versions of `proftp` available.

If you look at the list of files from lucid `mod_sql_passwd` is not present, but the file is present on oneric.

- http://packages.ubunut.com/lucid/amd64/proftpd-basic/filelist
- http://packages.ubunut.com/oneiric/amd64/proftpd-basic/filelist

Comment: That's the conclusion I had. Upgrading the distribution caused me some other issues, but it did solve the missing sql_passwd.